# How update v-model of a element that is changed programatically?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using a JS plugin for Checkbox.

This plugin creates a switch button that mimics the state of the checkbox.

When the switch button is toggled its change the `checked` value of the checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="active" class="switch">
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            active: false
        }
    })
</script>
```

However the `active`data value is only updated when the user clicks on the checkbox. Changing the checkbox `checked` attribute programmatically does not trigger the vue.

How can I update the vue `data` when the input is changed programmatically? for instance `$("#myinput").prop("checked",true)`

Comment: *This plugin creates a switch button that mimics the state of the checkbox.* <-- This can be achieved with the native checkbox and some intelligent CSS only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vue updates the `v-model`'s property whenever the `change`* event is triggered. Trigger it:

```js
$("#myinput").prop("checked", true);
$("#myinput")[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); // must trigger NATIVE event
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    active: false
  }
});

$("#via-jq").click(function() {
  let currChecked = $("#myinput").prop("checked");
  $("#myinput").prop("checked", !currChecked);
  $("#myinput")[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input id="myinput" type="checkbox" v-model="active" class="switch"> {{ active }}
</div>

<button id="via-jq">Toggle Via jQ</button>
```

* <sub>This is the case for `checkbox`es. The event varies according to input type. E.g. `input` event may trigger the update for other types of elements as well.</sub>

Comment: `dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))` works for `<select>` element too :)